# Stuff NSMutableDicitonary into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have following declarations:

```
 //.h file:
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;

    //.m file
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            
        currentElement = [elementName copy];
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"table"]){
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentEid = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentEname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentEurl = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        //NSLog(@"didStartElement");
        }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"table"]) {
            // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
            [item setObject:currentEname forKey:@"ename"];
            //NSLog(@"%@",item);
            [self.dataArray addObject:[item copy]];
            NSLog(@"%@",dataArray);
            }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
        if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"eid"]) {
            [currentEid appendString:string];
        } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"ename"]) {
            [currentEname appendString:string];
            //NSLog(@"%@",currentEname);
        } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"eurl"]) {
            [currentEurl appendString:string];
        } 
        //  NSLog(@"foundCharacters");
    }
```

I get null values for the `NSMutableArray(dataArray)` when displayed. How could I solve this?
Or if you could, assist me with knowledge on how to display the `NSMutableDicitonary` data in table view cells.

Comment: It's been a wee while now, how have you gotten on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `dataArray` is created. Put this in your class's `init` method or wherever else it would be appropriate:

```
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Also, I hope your iPhone has a lot of memory, as your code is leaking a fair bit.

Comment: Hey Thanks!!! DreamLax...Its working now.
But I dont know about leaking.. What is it???
Will you please help me again. I would like to display the same dataArray in the table view cells.How to do it??

Comment: iphone doesn't have a automatic garbage collector and the amount of memory availble to your application is very small.So for every alloc | retain | copy  you have to have a  release somewhere in your application.For effective memory management you can find a lots of document over web and also in this site.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the leaks dreamlax mentioned, you need to add code in front of this:

```
item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentEid = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentEname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentEurl = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

With something like this:

```
[item release]; [currentEid release]; [currentEname release]; [currentEurl release];
item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            currentEid = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            currentEname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            currentEurl = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

And also reelase them when you are done parsing...

Don't check my answer as correct though, dreamlax deserves the credit for pondering the code...

For populating a UITableView, you really need to work through some of the UITableView examples and see how they load data.

Comment: I personally would avoid having 4 separate statements on one line.

Comment: Normally I would not do that either, I just wanted to quickly illustrate they should be free... however it's quite common to put something like [item release]; item = nil on a single line as they are intimately related.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have a number of `alloc`s. These need to be balanced with `release`. You also have a `copy` that needs to be balanced with a `release`. If you don't release these objects, you will end up allocating new objects over and over, and you will eventually run out of memory.

What you need to do is figure out where in your code is a suitable place to release them. When you no longer need the objects that you allocated, you should release them. In your case, it may be sensible to add the following code in your `- (void)parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` method, like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"table"]) {
            // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
            [item setObject:currentEname forKey:@"ename"];
            //NSLog(@"%@",item);
            [self.dataArray addObject:[[item copy] autorelease]];
            NSLog(@"%@",dataArray);
            }
        [currentEid release];
        [currentEname release];
        [currentEurl release];
    }
```

Note that I also added an `autorelease` to your `copy`. `copy` useful because it creates an immutable copy of your object, which in this particular case might be what you're after. However, when you create a copy, you are the owner of the copy and you are responsible for releasing it. Your `dataArray` array will take ownership of your `item` copy when you add it with `addObject:`, but you must still relinquish your ownership by releasing it. However, we can't `release` it before we give it to the array, otherwise the `item` copy will be deallocated before it is given to `dataArray`, so it is auto-released instead. An autoreleased object is guaranteed to survive for at least the remainder of the method.

An alternative to autoreleasing is to manually keep track of the `item` copy, like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"table"]) {
            NSDictionary *itemCopy;
            // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
            [item setObject:currentEname forKey:@"ename"];
            //NSLog(@"%@",item);
            itemCopy = [item copy];
            [self.dataArray addObject:itemCopy];
            [itemCopy release];
            NSLog(@"%@",dataArray);
            }
        [currentEid release];
        [currentEname release];
        [currentEurl release];
    }
```